# Too much space between bars in matplotlib bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I am trying to create a bar chart with matplotlib.

The x-axis data is a list with years: [1950,1960,1970,1980,1990,1995-2015]

The y-axis data is a list with equal amount of numbers as in years.

This is my code:

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path = "bevoelkerung_entwicklung.csv"



with open(path, 'r') as datei:
    reader = csv.reader(datei, delimiter=';')
    jahr = next(reader)
    population = next(reader)

population_list = []

for p in population:
    population_list.append(str(p).replace("'",""))

population_list = list(map(int, population_list))
jahr = list(map(int, jahr))

datei.close()

plt.bar(jahr,population_list, color='c')

plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Population in 1000')
plt.title('Population growth')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

And the outcome is the following:
[Too much space between bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rnpi.png)

As you can see the gaps between 1950-1960 is huge. How can I make it, so that there is no gap inbetween the bars 1950-1995. I get that it has intervals of 10 years, but it doesn't look good.

Any help would be appreaciated.

Comment: So you want the width of the bars to adjust based on the x spacing? In that case, your bars would no longer be centered at the real data point

Comment: I think there are 26 entries. I'd like to have 26 bars having equal amount of space between them. That's what I'd like to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to plot the population data as a function of increasing integers. This makes the bars have equal spacings. You can then adapt the labels to be the years that each graph represents.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

jahre = np.append(np.arange(1950,2000,10), np.arange(1995,2017))
bevoelkerung = np.cumsum(np.ones_like(jahre))
x = np.arange(len(jahre))

plt.bar(x, bevoelkerung)
plt.xticks(x, jahre, rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[image]