# How can I draw side-by-side bars on a histogram in JFreeChart?

Tags: java, histogram, jfreechart

I am drawing a histogram in JFreeChart. The histogram has multiple series. I want a separate bar for each series in each bin. I want to draw the bars side by side –– not layered on top of each other. Unfortunately, JFreeChart layers the bars on top of each other. I tried to attach a screenshot of the histogram, but Stack Overflow said, "Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server." I found a similar question for matplotlib in Python.

[Server Error: Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420821/server-error-failed-to-upload-image-an-error-occurred-on-the-server)

[How do I show the histogram bars side by side on the same plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55599786/how-do-i-show-the-histogram-bars-side-by-side-on-the-same-plot)

Update 2022-10-14: Please find attached a screenshot of a histogram drawn by JFreeChart. Note that the bars from the blue series layer on top of the bars from the red series. I prefer to see the bars from both series side by side.

[image: Screenshot of histogram drawn by JFreeChart]

Comment: This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28519356/230513) uses transparency and visibility.

Comment: Can you use a `StackedXYBarRenderer`?

Comment: trashgod and Catalina Island: Thank you for your comments. I will try your ideas!